# Unexpected color flattening

Tags: rendering, camera, color-management, color

I am fresh to Blender and am making a futuristic-ish flying vehicle network. There are rows of rectangle groups all moving in different directions while the camera pans the scene.

In an arbitrary frame (which is around the middle of the animation, but NOT always the same frame), all objects are suddenly de-colorized and turn white for no apparent reason! Some seconds later, it returns to normal. This happens ONLY in camera perspective!

I've deleted the camera and re-added it to no avail. This is exactly how it looks:

Normal (with colors) in render view:

[image: Normal (with colors) in render view]

Problematic (white flattened) in render view

[image: Problematic (white flattened) in render view]

Any ideas????

Comment: Cycles or internal? How is your material applied? Is any of your colour vertex colour? Could you post photos out of render view, or even post the [.blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) if your comfortable?

Comment: Are the colors also 'flattened' when you render the scene? Are you doing any compositing? What kind of material have you given the objects?

Comment: @360ueck I use cycles. And really comfortable posting the .blend file because i am not sure if i can give you the appropriate info...!

Comment: @Cubit The objects are glass bsdf surfaces and emission volumes. About the compositing part, not sure i can enlighten you...

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/vfzwul the blend file...

Comment: @Cubit No, the verdict is that I am not compositing on this scene... I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn up your "saturation" and "value", otherwise it's mostly white glass and light. Add that to the extra emission from lamps and other objects and the cars just appear white at times.

[image: NODES SHADER ISSUE]

Comment: Totally noobish mistake...! Really thanks for the help!!!! :D